# Backup & Migrate scheduled backup silently fail

Tags: 7, cron, backups

I've tried to use backup & migrate for backups on my omega8 based aegir server.

Although I've defined a schedule, and setup cron interval to 1 hour, it doesn't work - no backups are generated. Scheduled backup silently fail.

Attached is a screenshot of the current schedule:

[image: Scheduled backup options]

Notes:

- Module's permissions are default (all marked V for admin).
- Backup profile is the default as well.
- I'm using Drupal 7. Module's version is 7.x-2.7

Any idea?

Comment: So what's in error.log? and how do you invoke cron? via wget? using drush? Using "poormanscron" method? If the last one, are you sure you have enough traffic to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using buggy module with known issues. This has nothing to do with BOA nor Aegir. There is a reason why we have removed this notoriously buggy module from BOA recently. You should report any such issues in the `backup_migrate` issue queue on drupal.org - and you may find them reported already, in fact.

This module may still be useful, but only if you follow its issue queue and use release which happens to work. The regressions rate in this module is way too high for us, so we no longer include it by default. Just one example:
https://drupal.org/node/1997354
and a fix:
https://drupal.org/node/1997354#comment-7426824

Comment: Show me one module with usage over 1k and without open issues...

Comment: In this case you have to update this post: https://omega8.cc/backups which still recommends Backup & Migrate and hopefully provide a free alternative which works.

Comment: Omega8 updated their post (https://omega8.cc/backups) with alternate methods using rsync.